# ComboBox.Selected Value return Null

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding

I'm having an issue with the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` where I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` even though I have a value in it. i get this error  after i close the  program it set the value  back to null i believe, because when i run it, it  works fine i can chose from the  comboBox but when i close,  i get that error.
 I connected the `comboBox` with Data Binding mode (image-A1) . Here is my code, hope you can help

```
    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedValue == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL");
        }
        else
        {

            label2.Text = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
   }
```

This is the query i'm using if it helps

```
 SELECT Company, Code FROM Companys ORDER BY Code
```

[image]

Comment: Try using the `SelectedValueChanged` event instead.  Does the query return any null records?

Comment: i  changed to selctedValueChanged still the same.

Comment: Is this because `SelectedIndexChanged` is firing when the combo is populated - and no selection has been made yet - or do you get this when you make a selection?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code after changing the selected item? Are you sure you are accessing the proper `ComboBox`? You can always cast the `sender` to a `ComboBox` and try using that object. If you inspect the `ComboBox` instance while debugging do you see items in the `Items` collection?

Comment: @stuartd i get this error  after i close the  program it set the value  back to null i believe because when i run it, it  works fine i can chose from the  comboBox but when i close,  i get that error..

Comment: `i get this error after i close the program`.  Important information you left out.  Do you have any code in the FormClosing event? Are you setting the DataSource to null at some point?  Yada-yada-yada...

Comment: @LarsTech Yes i do apologies for that i edit it  in i'm new. `This.Close();` no i'm not

Comment: @Carson Sorry for the delay, i stepped  though the code, everything is good till i exit the program.  i can see that after i click close the program goes to Combobox and set it to null. it goes  through this after i click  close is it somehow responsible ? `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }`

Comment: Are you setting the DataSource to null somewhere?  Because the code doesn't duplicate the issue unless you are setting that to null somewhere in your code.

Comment: When you call `this.Close()` does it trigger the `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: @LarsTech The form might set the binding to null in the Dispose automatically. Or the control does.

Comment: @Carson yes it does

Comment: So what's the issue? You just don't want the message to show up? Or does it throw an exception like `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Carson it throw an exception `NullReferenceExceptionNullReferenceException`

Comment: @LarsTech I don't think i'm

Comment: You are making this so difficult.  Getting a null value and getting a null exception are very different things.  Which line throws the error?  Use the debugger to inspect the values when the exception is thrown.

Comment: thank you all for your help. i'm  sorry for the difficulty i'm new to this world also English is not my first language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are accessing wrong combobox values,

It should be

```
 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedValue == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL");
        }
        else
        {    
            label2.Text = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry i edited the  question i still get the Null Value.

Comment: try  label2.Text = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: i do not have team viewer

Comment: did you try the above?

Comment: i just did still giving me a null value

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `NULL` in `comboBox2` and then trying to write the value from `comboBox1`. Presumably, `comboBox1` `SelectedValue` is `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry i edited the  question i still get the Null Value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Might work
    if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;

    // Or this
    if (comboBox == null)
        return;

    if (comboBox.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

It should skip the routine if the form is disposed. You can also try that check on the combobox itself, since it should inherit from [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I  Tried it, still getting the same results.

Comment: You stepped through this code? Is the `comboBox` instance `null` when this happens? If so, change the check to `if (comboBox == null) return;`

Comment: `if (comboBox.SelectedValue == null)` works it no  longer put it back to Null. Thank you so much for your help  and is there  a way to figure out why it is  going back to null?

Comment: Yes. Your form was disposing when you called `this.Close()` and in the dispose order it will dispose its children before it disposes itself. The comboBox is being set to null before the form is completely disposed. Since the event handler isn't being manually (I assume) removed from the comboBox, it must trigger that event sometime during the dispose. Potentially when the binding is disposed. [Some info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, make sure to include as much detail as possible in questions you post. Even if the detail seems innocuous it could actually lead to the answer. Similar to how we found the answer when you told me it was throwing a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

I faced your problem, and that what I found after many trials , I hope it will help.
where db is an object from my database in sql server
and have 2 tabels((1)Brand,(many) Model) 1 to many relation in sql
and model combobox is dependent on my selection of the Brand combobox

```
        private void Brand_Selected()
        {
            if (cbxBrand.SelectedValue == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                int id = int.Parse(cbxBrand.SelectedValue.ToString());
                List<Model> y = db.Model.Where(x => x.Brand_ID == id).ToList();
                cbxModel.DataSource = y;
                cbxModel.DisplayMember = "Name";
            }
        }
```